# Does having multiple quantum computers in parallel speed up Shor's Algorithm?

Tags: quantum-computer

Essentially, how useful is it to have multiple quantum computers in parallel if the goal is to, for example, recover a 2048 bit RSA key?

Comment: Just 2^1024 computers, and you can do it in (almost) constant time!

Comment: It is not clear at all what "in parallel" means here.  What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, parallel computing can reduce the time it takes to perform Shor's algorithm.

For example, the meat of Shor's algorithm is a modular exponentiation. Which you could perform via N conditional multiplications one after another. Instead of that, you could do $\sqrt{N}$ groups of $\sqrt{N}$ conditional multiplications, then do $\sqrt{N}$ multiplications to combine the intermediate results together into the final product, then uncompute the intermediate states with $\sqrt{N}$ groups of $\sqrt{N}$ conditional un-multiplications. This reduces the multiplication-depth from $N$ to $3 \sqrt{N}$.

Of course that's just a simple example. There's lots of other stuff you can do. Pick your favorite classical parallel binary multiplier circuit, and derive a quantum circuit from it. Or do even more multiplications in parallel.

That being said, quantum computers already need to operate every qubit constantly in order to perform error correction. So they are going to naturally be operated in a very parallel way. There's no need to wait for a second or third computer before you start thinking about parallelization.

Comment: Are your parallel quantum computers talking to each other? If yes, why not make them a big computer?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Given the lay phrasing of the question, I don't want to split hairs about what's "really" using multiple computers. Suffice it to say that some of the work can be done in parallel.

Comment: But is it any smarter than just to try them in parallel classically?  (I mean, in factoring one has to do mod. exp. w/ different exponents, and these can be parallelized, because the algorithm just tries one after the other. but that's not particularly quantum.  I guess you refer to sth. else?  To be honest, I don't understand your answer.  What is N?  And if your answer *does* parallelize in a quantum way, I'd first like to know what model you consider, and how this even differs from just having a larger quantum computer.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don't understand what you mean by classical-vs-quantum parallelization. To factor an N-bit number, [the naive circuit for Shor's algorithm performs N controlled modular multiplications](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Strilanc/PaperImpl-2017-DirtyPeriodFinding/master/doc/assets/shor-period-finding-solo-phase-qubit.png). Those controlled multiplications are commutative and associative. This allows you to group them, do the groups in parallel, then merge the groups. Because we need reversibility there is the additional step of uncomputing the intermediate groups.

Comment: I think my question can be summarized as follows: Is it required to pass quantum states from one quantum computer to another?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes. You have to get the intermediate products back into one place to combine them, and they have to stay coherent or the later uncomputation will fail.

Comment: But then how is this different from just having a single larger quantum computer?  And if it isn't, wouldn't it be faster to just run Shor on this machine?  Or do you claim you have found a new way to speed up Shor's algorithm?  Or is this all only about being able to execute gates in parallel (i.e., counting gates by depth)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It's just about running gates in parallel.

Comment: It might make sense to explain this in your answer.